# BizTalk 2009 File Adapter Send with Append Locking Issues

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

We have some EDI files coming in to our BizTalk server that we drop off on a file share for processing by an end system.  The files are dropped to the file share via a single File Send Port with a static file name.  The files are delivered with the Append option set as the end system only collects the files once a day.

We're running with a single host instance for the send port.  The file share is located on a seperate server.  When we go out to that server (Widnows 2008) and view the open files, we see two read locks on the file from the BizTalk host instance account.  The messages are suspending in BizTalk with Access Denied messages.  The files are written to the file share seperated by minutes and sometimes in the same minute.  None of the files are large (all < 20K).  This happens maybe once a week and happens on different file drop locations on the target server.  Recycling the host instance does not release the locks.  Ordered delivery doesn't help.

Any thoughts or input to solving the problem or troubleshooting would be helpful.  Some things I have been considering:

1. File adapter losing it's file handles?
2. Anybody use append mode in the file adapter with no issues before?

Thanks!

Comment: If you do not use append mode do you still get the problems? I try to avoid files at all costs normally. Can you not use a different transport like msmq?

Comment: We're locked into file... we could go to FTP if we needed to but that's not desirable.  The problem only manifests itself on Append mode writes.

Comment: In my experience file drops are not really designed for reliable transfer of data. I think FTP would be preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a known issue with the BizTalk file adapter.

"This is an issue with the append option because Biztalk reads to end of the file before appending."

From the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/e4fd1ef5-6861-4ac0-be36-b96bbf1e753d/).